# Java to C++ syntax

Tags: java, c++, input, while-loop, user-input

C++ beginner here. Wondering what the syntax is for this piece of Java code on restricting user input. Here is an example of a Java code I wrote

```
while (!in.hasNext("[A-Za-z]+")){}
```

Where "in" is my scanner variable. This piece of code runs when the input is not a real number, and returns an error message with the option to enter something in again. I haven't been able to find the equivalent of this "range" condition on C++. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:
I have tried using the regex function in Dev C++ but it gives me a warning like this:

```
 #ifndef _CXX0X_WARNING_H
 #define _CXX0X_WARNING_H 1

 #if __cplusplus < 201103L
 #error This file requires compiler and library support for the \
 ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support is currently experimental, and must be \
 enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.
 #endif

 #endif
```

Does this mean that I cant use the regex function in Dev C++?

Comment: You might search for _regular expressions_ (or regex) in C++.

Comment: What does that mean??

Comment: What you are calling a "range condition" is simply a _regular expression_, which most programming languages have capabilities for using. There is plenty of information out there for using them in C++.

Answer (score 0):

**Example:**

```
cin >> inputStr;
if (std::regex_match (inputStr, std::regex("[A-Za-z]+") )) {
    // do something, will you ?
}
```

Note: you will need to include `<regex>`.

**More info:** http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/regex_match/

Answer (score 0):

If you wan to loop until you get a real number then you can use:

```
do
{
    cin >> input;
} while(std::regex_match (input, std::regex("[A-Za-z]+")));
```

You can also use `std::stod()` to convert a `std::string` to a `double`.  Doing that will make sure you are getting a valid real number since a number and have e/E in it.  You can do that with:

```
std::string input;
double value;
size_t pos;
do
{
    cin >> input;
    value = stod(input, &pos);
} while (pos < input.size());
```